# Removing index.php CodeIgniter using WAMP shows Wampserver Homepage instead

Tags: codeigniter, wamp

I just started learning CodeIgniter and I want to remove the index.php so the URL can be shown nicely.

I'm using .htaccess but instead it shows me the Wampserver Homepage (like in http://localhost)

My project directory is in http://localhost/CodeIgniter

What's wrong?

Comment: delete index.php?Or remove index.php from url.

Comment: Oops sorry, English is not my primary language

Comment: Hm, strange, i guess you use well known .htaccess code, suggested on CI site?

Comment: http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php working?

Comment: I googled it before asking here. So, I used a lot of .htaccess from many sources

Comment: Yes localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php is working

Comment: I think you have .htaccess file at your localhost.Delete that .htaccess or write rules there too.First try with deleteing.If it works then fix that .htaccess

Comment: There's no .htaccess file there, write rules there didn't do anything.

Comment: Well what did you wrote your .htaccess file that is inside codeigniter folder also make sure your .htaccess working

Comment: provide your `.htaccess` code, so we can see what you have

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for this answer, it is due to not enabling mod_rewrite in the httpd.conf file.

Just remove the # from the start of the below line in the httpd.conf file to enable mod_rewrite.

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Restart the apache after that.

Answer (score 0):

Only three steps are require to remove index.php from url in Codeigniter in WAMP environment.

1) Create .htacess file in parallel to application holder and just copy past the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

2) Change $config['index_page'] to blank in config.php in application folder as below:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

3) Enable “rewrite_module” of apache.

Restart your apache and its done.

Details : http://sforsuresh.in/removing-index-php-from-url-of-codeigniter-in-wamp/